# What is the FQDN for localhost PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp, fqdn

I'm using the CodeIgniter (CI) PHP framework. It has issues when I do certain functions with the FTP class. A user recommended I try connecting to FTP under the FQDN. My question is what would that be for localhost?

Comment: Check the error log, what is the exact message you are getting?  `localhost` is a valid FQDN.

Comment: This is the error that kills the script: "An Error Was Encountered / Unable to delete the file". If I check the PHP Error log via WAMP it is blank...

Answer (score 2):

`localhost` is a FQDN. On most computers, it translates to `127.0.0.1` in IPv4 or `::1` in IPv6. I'd be tempted to look into port numbers and passive mode if you're having problems with FTP.

Comment: From what I've been looking through it appears FQDN is hostname.domainname.com and that by modifying the lmhosts file in system32/drivers you can manually point an ip to an alias (domain). So then I would be able to point a fake domain to my localhost directory...

Comment: By the letter of the law, `localhost` may not be a FQDN (can't find anything to back it up either way), but `localhost` is a DNS record in the eyes of your application, and is a DNS lookup like `example.com` is. If you're having problems with `localhost` you'll probably have problems with `example.com` as well. We probably need more information about what FTP server you're connecting to, and what exact errors your encountering to assist you better.

Comment: I'm connecting to a local FileZilla server I setup... by answering your question it lead me to answer my own. I looked in the FTP user's settings and it didn't have the necessary permissions... That is why I got the FTP errors I did... xD